# Getting warning regarding dependency analysis for DEFINES_Modules

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have recently added on `Swift` supported library in my project and currently my project primary language is `Objective-C` and due to this its showing some **dependency warning** in my project like below :

> warning: using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES' while building targets
>   which define modules ('DEFINES_MODULE = YES') may fail. Please migrate
>   to using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO'.

Any one have any idea how can I resolve above waring ?

As warning it self telling that need to set flag **'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO'** will resolve this warning.

But my question is : **is it affect any of existing functionality or linking framework issue by doing this ?**

or **its safe to do as directed in this waring ?**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Xcode 8.3 release, the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS is now deprecated, but other libraries that which are still using the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS are putting the setting value in your project, you will have to wait for other libraries make their changes too.

For example, current Core Plot is on version 2.2, it still put the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS value in my project, the fix for this warning will be released in version 2.3

Comment: But what about lower deployment target ? like I have to provide support of 8.0 and grater in that case ?

Comment: Please see updated answer to see if it will fix your warnings.